# How to force linq to Sql to execute query straight away

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a repeater of controls on an aspx page. I am trying to move a query out of the control and into the parent page as there is a massive hit on the DB for each control. The problem is that I get the following error.

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.
```

I don't understand this as I thought that doing .ToList() forces the query to be executed

My code in the Parent page

```
Private _activityList As IEnumerable(Of Activity)
Public ReadOnly Property ActivityList() As IEnumerable(Of Activity)
    Get
        Return _activityList
    End Get
End Property

Sub PopulatePage()
    Dim activityList = From a In dbContext.Activities Where a.PA.PA_Key.ToUpper().Trim() = "DCC" _
        Select a

    _activityList = activityList.AsEnumerable()
End Sub
```

The code in my control is:

```
Public _activityList As List(Of Activity)
Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    _activityList = CType(Me.Page, ParentPage).ActivityList.ToList()
End Sub

Sub grdSelectedActivities_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.WebControls.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles grdSelectedActivities.NeedDataSource

    Dim lnqActivities = _activityList
    Dim objActivity As Activity = (From x In lnqActivities Where x.AC_Code = ActivityCode Select x).Single

    Dim lnqRoundActivities = (From roundactivity In objActivity.RoundActivities Where roundactivity.RA_DS_Code = DepartmentalSettingsCode 
                                  Select roundactivity Order By roundactivity.RA_Name)

    grdSelectedActivities.DataSource = lnqRoundActivities
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I think that is is failing as it is trying to get RoundActivities in the `grdSelectedActivities_NeedDataSource` control method. Therefore I need to send an Activities object which has RoundActivityies child objects.

I have tried to create this object but get the following error:

```
Explicit construction of entity type 'Activity' in query is not allowed.
enter code here
```

This is the updated code:

```
 Dim activityList = (From a In dbContext.Activities Where a.PA.PA_Key.ToUpper().Trim() = "DCC" Select New Activity With {.AC_Code = a.AC_Code, .RoundActivities = a.RoundActivities})
```

**Solution:**

I followed @kristoferA advice and did the following

```
Dim loadOptions = New DataLoadOptions()
loadOptions.LoadWith(Of Activity)(Function(a As Activity) a.RoundActivities)
loadOptions.AssociateWith(Of Activity)(Function(a As Activity) a.RoundActivities.Where(Function(z) If(z.RA_DS_Code = departmentCode, False)))
dataContext.LoadOptions = loadOptions
```

Comment: @Emmie It seems to be erring when trying to access RoundActivities during databind. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are lazy loading some association.

Turn off lazy loading (dc.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false), and pass a DataLoadOptions object to dc.LoadOptions to instruct the DC what you want to eager load.

Comment: Can you add implementation of the DataLoadOptions please

Comment: I was about to, and then I saw you already added the dataloadoptions example to the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guest that the **dbContext** get disposed after PopulatePage() done and your Linq select return type is IEnumerable(Of Activity) which's just a prepared SQL statement.

try..

```
_activityList = activityList.ToList()//.AsEnumerable()
```

### Edit

if your Model is stateless you can create new dbContext then enumerate and dispose it.

```
Using db As New dbContext()

    Dim activityList = (From a In dbContext.Activities Where a.PA.PA_Key.ToUpper().Trim() = "DCC" _
    Select a).ToList()

    _activityList = activityList.ToList()
End Using
```

Comment: @skyfoot When/Where does the dbContext instant come from. through [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) see updates

Answer (score 0):

ai.farfa is correct with the ToList(). That is the call that trigger the actual query.
I think you should do it on this line though :

```
 grdSelectedActivities.DataSource = lnqRoundActivities.ToList()
```

Comment: this doesn't work either. I believe that it doesnt even have the RoundActivites in the Activity object at that stage. hence the error.